# Cannot subscribe to Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic if the topic is in String values

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging to show push notifications in the Android app. The notification is sent as soon as the user creates new request in the app.
To see notifications, users subscribe to the Cloud Messaging topic "newRequests".
The trick is notifications won't work if I declare topic name in the string values xml file (as we should do for any string values as per best practices).
Instead, I need to write "newRequests" right in the main body of the executing code to make it work. Why it works this way? How can we get notifications by placing topic name in the string values?

On the Firebase server side, my function is:

```
exports.notifyOnCreatedRequest = functions.firestore.document('requests/{requestId}')
.onCreate((document, context) => {
    const data = document.data();
    const description = data.description;
    const topic = 'newRequests';

    const message = {
        notification: {
            title: "New request",
            body: description,
        },
    data: {
      "requestId" : context.params.requestId
    },
        topic: topic
    };

    admin.messaging().send(message)
      .then((response) => { console.log('Successfully sent message:', response); })
      .catch((error) => { console.log('Error sending message:', error); });
```

});

The mobile app code subscribes to the topic as follows:

```
Firebase.messaging.subscribeToTopic("newRequests")
```

And this works fine. However I would like to do it this way:

```
Firebase.messaging.subscribeToTopic(R.string.new_requests.toString())
```

And to declare string value in strings.xml file:

```
<string name="new_requests">"newRequests"</string>
```

Which doesn't work. When I use value from xml, onSuccessListener for the subscribe task returns success with no errors for subscription. Also, I tried to put string value in xml with single quotes (as in JS function) with backslash, however than string values file won't compile.

UPDATE:
Thanks to the answer below, the problem was that R.string.new_requests return int instead of string. This is a commonly known problem with Android, it was discussed a lot in another stackoverflow answers. So e. g. walkaround to resolve this could be something like:

```
        @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    private fun turnOffNotifications(){
        Firebase.messaging.unsubscribeFromTopic(
            getApplicationContext().resources.getString(R.string.new_requests)) }
```

Comment: any update here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there shouldn't be quotes around the value in the XML, so:

```
<string name="new_requests">newRequests</string>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work. Just tried again. I remove quotes and my resource is <string name="new_requests">newRequests</string> as you advice. On the other side, I use Firebase.messaging.subscribeToTopic(R.string.new_requests.toString()). And that doesn't work. As soon as I remove the resource and hardcode "newRequests" into Firebase.messaging.subscribeToTopic("newRequests"), it works...

Comment: You may have more problems in your implementation, but this was definitely one of them. String values in the XML file should not have quotes around them, unless you want to quotes to be part of the actual value of that string. --- I recommend stepping through the code in a debugger, and seeing what value you end up passing to `subscribeToTopic` in both cases to see the difference.

Comment: Thanks, it seems like you were right. R.string.my_string returned int value instead of string. This is a commonly known problem, so I updated my question with the walkaround